# Uploading video files to the Twitter API in chunks

Tags: .net, api, file-upload, twitter, oauth

I'm banging my head against my keyboard for a whole day now trying to figure out how to upload video files to the Twitter API. The API wants the video in chunks of max. 5mb. The procedure has 3 steps: **INIT, APPEND and FINALIZE**.

I am going trough all these steps without problems, but then in the last step when I finalize the upload the API returns the following message: **Segments do not add up to provided total file size.**.

So i'm guessing that the value I set for total_bytes in the INIT step isn't equal to sum of all Base64 encoded chunks I am sending.

I have tried different things to fix my problem but without any luck. I hope anyone here can help me out! Here is the code:

**INIT**

```
Dim MovieInfo As New FileInfo(Attachment)
Dim MovieType As String = "video/mpeg"
Dim PostParams As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
Dim MediaID As String = ""
Dim APIResponse As String = ""
Dim APIObject

PostParams.Clear()
PostParams.Add("command", "INIT")
PostParams.Add("total_bytes", MovieInfo.Length)
PostParams.Add("media_type", MovieType)
APIResponse = Generic.PostToTwitter(TwitCreds, "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json", PostParams)
APIObject = Json.Decode(APIResponse)
```

**APPEND**

```
Dim Buffer = New Byte(1 * 1024 * 1024) {}
Dim BytesRead As Integer = 0
Dim FileStream = New System.IO.FileStream(Attachment, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite)
Dim ChunkNr As Integer = 0

Try
    Do
        BytesRead = FileStream.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)
        If BytesRead > 0 Then
            PostParams.Clear()
            PostParams.Add("command", "APPEND")
            PostParams.Add("media_id", MediaID)
            PostParams.Add("segment_index", ChunkNr)
            PostParams.Add("media", Convert.ToBase64String(Buffer))
            APIResponse = Generic.PostToTwitter(TwitCreds, "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json", PostParams)
            ChunkNr += 1
        End If
    Loop While (BytesRead > 0)
Catch ex As Exception
    MediaID = ""
End Try

FileStream.Close()
FileStream.Dispose()
```

**FINALIZE**

```
PostParams.Clear()
PostParams.Add("command", "FINALIZE")
PostParams.Add("media_id", MediaID)
APIResponse = Generic.PostToTwitter(TwitCreds, "https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json", PostParams)
APIObject = Json.Decode(APIResponse)
```

**POST**

```
Dim oAuth As New oAuthBase
Dim Nonce As String = oAuth.GenerateNonce()
Dim Timestamp As String = oAuth.GenerateTimeStamp()
Dim NormalizedUrl As String = ""
Dim NormalizedRequestParameters As String = ""
Dim Signature As String = ""
Dim AuthorizationHeader As String = ""
Dim ResponseString As String = ""
Dim oAuthData As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
Dim PostResult As HttpResponseMessage

oAuthData.Add("oauth_consumer_key", TwitCreds.ConsumerKey)
oAuthData.Add("oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1")
oAuthData.Add("oauth_timestamp", Timestamp)
oAuthData.Add("oauth_nonce", Nonce)
oAuthData.Add("oauth_token", TwitCreds.OAuthToken)
oAuthData.Add("oauth_version", "1.0")

Signature = Generic.GenerateSignature(TwitCreds, Url, FormData, oAuthData)

oAuthData.Add("oauth_signature", Signature)

Dim oAuthHeader As String = String.Format( _
    "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=""{0}"", " & _
    "oauth_nonce=""{1}"", " & _
    "oauth_signature=""{2}"", " & _
    "oauth_signature_method=""HMAC-SHA1"", " & _
    "oauth_timestamp=""{3}"", " & _
    "oauth_token=""{4}"", " & _
    "oauth_version=""1.0""",
    TwitCreds.ConsumerKey.UrlEncode,
    Nonce.UrlEncode,
    Signature.UrlEncode,
    Timestamp.UrlEncode,
    TwitCreds.OAuthToken.UrlEncode)

Using MyClient As New HttpClient

    MyClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", oAuthHeader)

    If Not FormData Is Nothing Then
        PostResult = MyClient.PostAsync(Url, New MyFormUrlEncodedContent(FormData)).Result
    Else
        PostResult = MyClient.PostAsync(Url, Nothing).Result
    End If

    If Not PostResult Is Nothing Then
        ResponseString = PostResult.Content.ReadAsStringAsync.Result
    End If

End Using

Return ResponseString
```

Comment: Untill now I don't have a solution for the problem I was facing when uploading chunked video, but in my search I stumbled upon a great library called Tweetinvi ([link](https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi)). 

Video upload worked withing 30 minutes after downloading. 

Thanks @Linvi!